# PyQt5, how to open new window after click QButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, click, pyqt5

I clicked the button Platform Type, but Ui_Form doesn't show

I tried `exec_()` but Process finished with `exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

I want to open new QWidget window when clicked the button

**Details**: In Python, I want to make one more window when I press the button of the first widget. I tried to follow the other contents, but the program terminated with an error code. I would appreciate if you could let me know what the problem is.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Main_Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._mutex = QtCore.QThread()
        self.setupUi(Main_Widget)

    def setupUi(self, Main_Widget):
        Main_Widget.setObjectName('Main_Widget')
        Main_Widget.resize(1272, 640)

        self.All_GroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Main_Widget)
        self.All_GroupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 1231, 611))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.All_GroupBox.setFont(font)
        self.All_GroupBox.setObjectName('All_GroupBox')

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.All_GroupBox)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 261, 331))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName('verticalLayoutWidget')

        self.Button_VerticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Button_VerticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.Button_VerticalLayout.setObjectName('Button_VerticalLayout')

        self.PlatformType_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.PlatformType_Button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 45))
        self.PlatformType_Button.setObjectName('PlatformType_Button')
        self.Button_VerticalLayout.addWidget(self.PlatformType_Button)

    def PlatformType_Clicked(self):
        dialog = Ui_Form(self)
        self.dialogs.append(dialog)
        dialog.show()
        dialog.exec_()

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__(parent)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName('Form')
        Form.resize(422, 190)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_Widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Main_Widget()
    Main_Widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Main_Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
#        self._mutex = QtCore.QThread()
#        self.setupUi(Main_Widget)

    def setupUi(self, Main_Widget):
        Main_Widget.setObjectName('Main_Widget')
        Main_Widget.resize(1272, 640)

        self.All_GroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Main_Widget)
        self.All_GroupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 1231, 611))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.All_GroupBox.setFont(font)
        self.All_GroupBox.setObjectName('All_GroupBox')

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.All_GroupBox)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 261, 331))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName('verticalLayoutWidget')

        self.Button_VerticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Button_VerticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.Button_VerticalLayout.setObjectName('Button_VerticalLayout')

        self.PlatformType_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("PlatformType_Button", self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.PlatformType_Button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 45))
        self.PlatformType_Button.setObjectName('PlatformType_Button')
# +++        
        self.PlatformType_Button.clicked.connect(Main_Widget.PlatformType_Clicked) # +++

        self.Button_VerticalLayout.addWidget(self.PlatformType_Button)

#    def PlatformType_Clicked(self):
#        dialog = Ui_Form(self)
#        self.dialogs.append(dialog)
#        dialog.show()
#        dialog.exec_()

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__(parent)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName('Form')
        Form.resize(422, 190)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):                     # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Main_Widget() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

# +++
    def PlatformType_Clicked(self):
        self.dialog = Ui_Form()            # --- self
#        self.dialogs.append(dialog)
        self.dialog.show()
#        self.dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> hide() and show() method you can use multiple dialog what ever you want,...

`def PlatformType_Clicked(self):
dialog.hide()
dialog1.show()`

Comment: thank you sir. but in my code, show or exec_ doesn't work and window is closed just finish with exit code.